# JFace FontRegistry Font Disposal

Tags: dispose, jface

I have an application which will have many windows, so it makes sense to me to create a singleton that holds a `FontRegistry` instance and have that singleton manage the `FontRegistry`'s contents. My code looks something like this:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public final class FontRegistryManager {
    public static final FontRegistryManager INSTANCE = new FontRegistryManager();

    FontRegistry fr;

    private FontRegistryManager() {
        fr = new FontRegistry();

        Display currentDisplay = Display.getCurrent();
        Font mainFont = new Font(currentDisplay, "Tahoma", 8, 0);           
        fr.put(FontRegistryConstants.MAIN_FONT, mainFont.getFontData());
        mainFont.dispose();
    }

    public FontRegistry getFR() {
        return fr;
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is, am I right to immediately dispose of `mainFont`?

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with disposing the font right here, as long as it doesn't escape with code block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you instantiated it, you need to dispose it *sometime*. The best time is immediately after you don't need it anymore :) However, @strangeoptics is right that you don't actually need to create the font at all.